# Accessing link from URL redirecting to angular app not working

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm fairly new to angular and I want to understand how routing works. I have created an application when user registers and an email will be sent to them containing a link for verification. The verification route contains the user's id and verification code. When I try to access the link, the application doesn't seem to load properly and produces errors.

Here's my route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'index',
    component: IndexComponent
},
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
},
{
    path: 'signup',
    component: SignupComponent
},
{
    path: 'verify/:userId/:code',
    component: VerifyComponent,
},
];
```

These components are under a module called 'Public'.

I'm not sure if this is helpful but here is my AppModule imports:

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
AppAsideModule,
AppBreadcrumbModule.forRoot(),
AppFooterModule,
AppHeaderModule,
AppSidebarModule,
PerfectScrollbarModule,
BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
TabsModule.forRoot(),
ChartsModule,
AccountSettingModule,
DashboardModule,
PublicModule,
HttpClientModule
],
```

I have read that this can work by using hash, but I'm trying to steer away from it. I've also read about URL Rewrite but I haven't dig deep on it yet.

Note: I can also experience the app not loading when inputting the routes manually on the browser on some of my components.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:

Here's the sample link I'm using:

```
http://localhost:4200/verify/ba2b6e7a-d508-42b6-7b7e-08d691922233/CfDJ8Itsl344PZFNhS%2BBl0gYyOeKez6UhdY8fDyNrZLI4TudMlmHSiYdYsILhvXzwRPIDBG1X4tN7WBOD5WpPMEFBqoEdkdiEju2bf61hrLHAkR6SkFx5tvAZMeYrDkIR0iRjDgIAfSg6g1JUhiv9z9sSfiTthC2sQGI6ERZ5CidNKP6qADpMeshvowekRGLEprfeSNQaYW%2BxeIBpty38UEkdakHiTpFHsOnTyvgUU%2BC6gnw
```

And here's how I'm trying to get it on my VerifyComponent:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.userId = params.get('userId');
      this.code = params.get('code');

      this._authService.verifyCode({ UserId: this.userId, Code: this.code}).subscribe(res => {
        //do something after code is validated
        },
        error => console.log(error))
      },
      error => this._router.navigate(['/login']))

    });
  }
```

Comment: can you post the code where you try to read the url params? . .and also an example of the url you're testing?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi please see my edited answer.